# bottomnav FindViewById get null (kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, findviewbyid

I am trying to implement bottom navigation with an `Activity` and use Kotlin. So I search in youtube and I seen a lot of content which uses `Fragment` for bottom navigation T_T

So I try to copy code from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjfSjMs0ImQ because they use `Activity` not `Fragment`

But the problem is they use Java. So I try to convert the code to Kotlin. And then this happened (Logcat)

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: bottomNavigationView must not be null
>        at com.example.smscandroid.Profile.onCreate(Profile.kt:18)

So I look in Profile.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile)

    //init
    val bottomNavigationView =
        findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)
    //Set
    bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.profile
    //Perform ItemSelectedListener
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
        when (menuItem.itemId) {
            R.id.medication -> {
                startActivity(
                    Intent(
                        applicationContext
                        , Medication::class.java
                    )
                )
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.home -> {
                startActivity(
                    Intent(
                        applicationContext
                        , MainActivity::class.java
                    )
                )
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.profile -> return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        false
    })
}
```

I think the error is at

```
//init
val bottomNavigationView =
    findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)
//Set
bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.profile
```

I think `findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)` might get `null`
then `bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.profile` would cause an `Exception`

This is bottom_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/medication"
        android:title="medication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_medication"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:title="profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"/>
</menu>
```

Why does `findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)` get `null`?

If I write something wrong, tell me, I will improve it.

Comment: Does ***activity_profile.xml*** file contain a BottomNavigation with id ***bottom_navigation***?

Comment: Can you add your `R.layout.activity_profile` xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a file named activity_profile.xml in your res/layout that looks like this:

```
<SomeLayout
   ...
   >

    <BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/this_is_the_id_you_should_use"
        .../>

</SomeLayout>
```

And then in your Profile.kt you should use

```
val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.this_is_the_id_you_should_use)
```